# Minimum tls configuration not working in docker private repository

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, docker-registry

Using below configuration to set minimum tls version in Docker private registry.

```
http:
  addr: 0.0.0.0:5000
  net: tcp
  relativeurls: false
  draintimeout: 60s
  host: https://example.com:443
  tls:
    certificate: /certs/domain.crt
    key: /certs/domain.key
    minimumtls: tls1.3
    ciphersuites:
      - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
      - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

But when u run below command. It is showing tlsv1 is enabled.

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1
********
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: A611949FBC6ED8ED322D4360C7B32887C75BE6HJFU5BA9B536C3721924A103F3E
********
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information. How did you set up your cluster? Which version do you have? Did you deploy some ingress in your cluster? Did you test your tls in 1.2 version? In some cases 1.3 version is still not supported.

Comment: I am just trying to set minimum tls version in docker private registry which is outside of my Kubernetes cluster. I am able to set minimal tls in my ingress.

Comment: And what is the effect? Do you have any progress?